# react-i18next - import i18n instance & use directly vs using useTranslation hook

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I have a project written in React & support hooks.
I'm trying to use react-i18next to support translations.
Everything works well as I've follow the documentation.

However I stumble upon some problems when I want to use the `t()` function on helpers / non-component .js files.
Then, I solved it by importing i18n directly from the init file `./i18n.ts` that looks something like this

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) 
  .init({
    resources,

    ns: [
      'common',
      'dashboard',
      'landing'
    ],
    defaultNS: 'common',

    fallbackLng: 'en',
    supportedLngs: ['de', 'en'],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, 
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

and I realized that I don't have to use the hook at all since I can just use it like this anywehre across the code, even on my functional component file

```js
import i18n from "@root/i18n"

...
i18n.t('namespace:path')
```

I would like to know why is it recommended to use the `useTranslation` hook / `withTranslation` HOC if you can just import it like this?
I read that `useTranslation` apply suspense but it seems like the `initReactI18next` also have suspense applied by default.

I'm curious on if there's any side-effect on not using the recommended hook / HOC ?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/1042#issuecomment-572959286) answer on their github issues.

> But those constants never will be updated on languageChange! So
> either:
>
> - update them to new language value based on event triggered by i18next: https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onlanguagechanged
> - or better have only the keys in the constants and translate as close to the rendering as possible